# Line Break in String in config/locale internationalization file to show proper language format in view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

My client wants a string to show up as two sentences in the front. I am having trouble figuring out how I can do this.

for example in my config/locales/he-IL.yml file I have this

```
  home:
    instructions: "I am the world, please like ruby"
```

in my view I want it to show up as

```
I am the world please 
            like ruby
```

its actually in hebrew, it should look like this

```
הכנס את קוד זיהוי המחקר שלך וקוד המשתתף שלך לשדות הבאים. נא ליצור קשר
                                           עמנו אם יש לך שאלות נוספות.
```

please note that its read from right to left. Right now I have it lump as one piece of string so its not entirely viewed correctly in the front.

I have tried double quoting, using a new line, google for regular expressions and checking out the rails internationalization docs. would anyone have an answer for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use html tags inside. Just add `_html`.

```
home:
    instructions_html: |
                  I am the world, <br/>
                  please like ruby
```